How to add dropdown value to span text?
I have a page with a dropdown choice box. I would like the value of the option selected to update the text in a span which is also on the same page.
I have tried the following code, which works for text input and radio button selection but it doesn't seem to work for drop down choice selectors:
<select name="lastcontactmethod" id="lastcontactmethod>" class="text-input"><option value="none" selected disabled hidden>How...</option><optgroup label="Voice Call"><option value="Voice Call">Voice Call</option><option value="WhatsApp Call">WhatsApp Call</option><option value="Facebook Messenger Call">Facebook Messenger Call</option></optgroup><optgroup label="Text Message"><option value="SMS Message">SMS Message</option><option value="WhatsApp Message">WhatsApp</option><option value="Facebook Message">Facebook Messenger</option><option value="Snapchat Message">Snapchat</option><option value="Instagram">Instagram</option><option value="TikTok Message">TikTok</option></optgroup><optgroup label="Other"><option value="Letter / Note">Letter / Note</option></optgroup></select>

<span id="lastcontactmethod-display" class="item-display"> </span>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#lastcontactmethod').change(function() {
    var value = $(this).val().replace(/\n/g, '<br/>');
    $("#lastcontactmethod-display").html(value);
});
</script>


it doesn't seem to work for drop down choice selectors; what does happen? Is there an error? What steps have you taken to debug it?

You have a typo in your select id:
<select name="lastcontactmethod" id="lastcontactmethod>"
Should be:
<select name="lastcontactmethod" id="lastcontactmethod"
Notice the extra > char in your id name, making it not match your jQuery.
With this character removed, the code works.


$('#lastcontactmethod').change(function() {
    var value = $(this).val().replace(/\n/g, '<br/>');
    $("#lastcontactmethod-display").html(value);
});
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="lastcontactmethod" id="lastcontactmethod" class="text-input"><option value="none" selected disabled hidden>How...</option><optgroup label="Voice Call"><option value="Voice Call">Voice Call</option><option value="WhatsApp Call">WhatsApp Call</option><option value="Facebook Messenger Call">Facebook Messenger Call</option></optgroup><optgroup label="Text Message"><option value="SMS Message">SMS Message</option><option value="WhatsApp Message">WhatsApp</option><option value="Facebook Message">Facebook Messenger</option><option value="Snapchat Message">Snapchat</option><option value="Instagram">Instagram</option><option value="TikTok Message">TikTok</option></optgroup><optgroup label="Other"><option value="Letter / Note">Letter / Note</option></optgroup></select>
<span id="lastcontactmethod-display" class="item-display"> </span>




You won't believe how much time I've spent trying to work that out! Just goes to show what a fresh pair of eyes can do! Thanks for the help.

@Ush0934 No problem! :) With issues like this, you can solve them quicker by narrowing down where the problem is happening. For example, you could insert a console.log("change triggered!") at the start of your function, and then check your js console when you select an item to see if it is even getting that far. Then, for example, you would know that the issue is not with .val() or setting the span .html but actually with the .change not even firing in the first place! Then maybe console.log($('#lastcontactmethod')); and you'd find out that your selector never matched anything!
